# How to open a subdirectory with haskell

Tags: haskell

How can I open a file in a subDirectory?
I'm trying to build a crafting guide to a game, but for that I need to open the file on a sub Directory (In this case \crafting). I tried doing this, but it doesn't work:

```
main = do 
  a <- getLine
  b <- readFile ("/crafting/" ++ a ++".txt")
  putStrLn b
```

The error I got is that it doen'st find the file, but it is there.
When I use the full directory it works:

```
main = do 
 a <- getLine
 b <- readFile ("C:\\Users\\Utilizador\\Desktop\\Ash's Games\\Haskell\\Mega Survival\\crafting\\" ++ a ++".txt")
 putStrLn b
```

But it works when it is like this.

Comment: Paste any and all errors you got.

Comment: It can depend a bit on how you are compiling and running your program, as well; make sure you include a few details on that.

Comment: If using the relative path doesn't work, but the absolute path does... chances are the program is being started in a different directory than you think it is. Note that "/crafting/..." is not a relative directory - the leading forward slash is interpreted as the root directory of unix-like file systems, even on windows.

Comment: you are mixing forward and back slashes, plus you can't tell between relative and asbolute paths. seems to have nothing to do with Haskell.

Comment: if in doubt try `./crafting/...`

Comment: @user2407038, I never heard of the forward slash meaning that on Windows. Is that true in general, or only the GHC libraries?

Comment: @dfeuer Well I guess what I meant was, it is interpreted as the "analog" of the unix root on windows, which is the root of the current drive. There is no "global" root on Windows as far as I know, not even a very well hidden one as things tend to be on Windows, except perhaps at the kernel level. So if you start this program in any directory on the C: drive then `/crafting` refers to `C:/crafting`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `("crafting\\" ++ a ++".txt")`.

But more generally, you should not be manipulating filepaths with string functions. The [FilePath](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/filepath-1.4.1.0/docs/System-FilePath-Windows.html) library is a much better approach.